# Cannot import cassandra.cluster with python django

Tags: python, django, cassandra

I get this error when I try to include a cass.py file in the views for my web app: "No module named cassandra"

cass.py

```
from datetime import datetime
from uuid import uuid1, UUID
import random
import cassandra
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster

cluster = Cluster(['127.0.0.1'])
session = cluster.connect('project')
```

When I run this in my python shell from the command line it works fine so I don't think that it is any installation issue. Maybe django is just not finding the cassandra module? the path of the module is

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cassandra/__init__.pyc
```

Any ideas on how I can get django to find the cassandra module so I can use it?

Comment: what os & Python version you are using ?

Comment: python 2.7.6 on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: there is lot of way to check and solve the problem. using virtualenv you can isolate the environment. Second option in the cassandra may be deleting the pyc file will give you output

Comment: For the time being, I just moved all the cassandra files into the top level of my django app directory so that I can at least continue developing while I try to figure something out. Thanks for the input.

Comment: @Kyle Have you tried using django-cassandra-engine?